# How can I install the dicom gem using rvm on ubuntu 11?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have rvm installed, and the default set to 1.9.2.  Whenever I try to get the dicom gem, I get these error messages:

```
$ rvmsudo gem install dicom
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

These errors happen after I run the instructions [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/), ie:

```
$ rvmsudo rvm remove ruby-1.9.2
$ rvmsudo rvm pkg install zlib
$ rvmsudo rvm install ruby-1.9.2
$ rvmsudo --default use 1.9.2
```

These errors also happen after removing all sudo apt-get installed ruby versions (ie, I ran sudo apt-get remove ruby*), and uses the most recent rvm (1.8 as of this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM instructions tell that you have to install ruby this way

```
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

after installing zlib package

Comment: got it!  I thought that the second portion of the instructions would work, but I guess not.